# How to filter DataTable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have `DataTable` which brings me following data from database.

- `Name`
- `Address`
- `CountryID`

I want to filter the data on my side by LINQ: I have a checkbox list which has countries with IDs 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to get only results of the countries that are checked. e.g. 1, 2, 4 as CountryID by LINQ. And I want to bind that to grid view.

I am using the following code:

```
foreach (ListItem cBox in chkGodownlst.Items)
{ 
    if (cBox.Selected)
    {
        var a = dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<int>("CountryID") == Convert.ToInt32(cBox.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: I have multiple checked item. so i have to loop that and want to get all list of data which countries are checked

Comment: You need to get the ienumerable from the dt? or from the listbox? do they both hold the same references?

Comment: I have huge collection of data. and i have a checkbox list. and i want that what ever Id is checked the data should be filter

Comment: @MoizKachwala then why are you looping through dt?You need only checkbox list. Anyway you got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Get all checked id's.
var ids = chkGodownlst.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
    .Where(cBox => cBox.Selected)
    .Select(cBox => cBox.Value)
    .ToList();

// Now get all the rows that has a CountryID in the selected id's list.
var a = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => 
    ids.Any(id => id == r.Field<int>("CountryID"))
);

// Create a new table.
DataTable newTable = a.CopyToDataTable();

// Now set the new table as DataSource to the GridView.
```

Comment: @MoizKachwala What do you mean? Do you mean the `ids` variable?

Comment: code is working but the gridview is not getting Column fields

Comment: Set `a` to the `DataSource` property of the GridView and then call `Databind()` method on the GridView if it's asp.net.

Comment: not its not working. and whats this "id" means in following code --> Any(id => id == r.Field<int>("CountryID"))

Comment: `id` is the `cBox.Value` in the first LINQ: `.Select(cBox => cBox.Value);`. The same way `r` in `.Where(r =>` is the `DataRow` from `dt.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18666/discussion-between-moiz-kachwala-and-mario)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one :

```
var collection = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (ListItem cBox in chkGodownlst.Items)
{
   if(cBox.Selected)
   {
       collection.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("CountryID") == Convert.ToInt32(cBox.Value)));
   }
}

GridView1.DataSource = collection;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope this will help !!